# How do you turn off network printer discovery notifications in Ubuntu 20?

Tags: networking, 20.04, printing, notification

How do you stop network printer discovery notifications in Ubuntu 20?

I made the mistake of connecting a laser printer to my local network. Now Ubuntu constantly spams me with "Printer blah blah detected" modal popups, and even the printer selection dialog contains numerous duplicate printer listings.

How do I disable these notifications, but not actual usage of networked printing?

Answer (score 2):

Two simple commands in terminal will disable auto-adding of printers in Ubuntu:

```
sudo systemctl stop cups-browsed
sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed
```