# How do you silence all printer notifications?

Tags: networking, printing

I have a shared printer, connected via USB on a machine on my network, and every 15 seconds, Ubuntu shows a little "Printer error: Printer M2020: connecting-to-device" growl at the top of my screen.

I have a few different wireless networks, and it's only available on one of them, so I suspect when I'm not on the network with the printer, it constantly tries to connect to the printer and fails.

And it's driving me insane. I have no idea why an Ubuntu dev thought anyone needed to know when their machine was trying to connect to a printer.

How do I turn this off?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you turn off network printer discovery notifications in Ubuntu 20?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422345/how-do-you-turn-off-network-printer-discovery-notifications-in-ubuntu-20)